# Flexbox: div ignore height property

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm building a modal with flexbox, that has a two row design:

```
|-------------------|
|          A        |
|-------------------|
|                   |
|         B         |
|                   |
|                   |
|-------------------|
```

Since both A and B are part of a modal with height express in percentage and not in px I use flexbox in order to give to A an height and then to make B fill the rest of the space with an optional scrollbar if needed.

In order to achieve this I use the following html + css :

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="A"></div>
    <div class="B"></div>
</div>

.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: colum;
    height: 100%;
}

.A {
    height: 70px;
    width: 100%;
}

.B {
    margin: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
    flex: 1;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

The problem is that depending on the content of B, the height of A changes. With some content is fixed to 70px, with some other content is maybe 24px and if I inspect the css rules I can see that the height is 24px and when I click on the rule it highlights me the "height: 70px" line of code.

If I remove the "display: flex" in the wrapper the height remains correct with any kind of content but the div B overflow the modal and ignores completely the rule "overflow-y: auto".

How can I solve this?

Comment: It's `flex-direction: column` and not `colum`.

Comment: `height:100%` should be calculated from which parent's value if any, ?  fixing the typo and the height to a valid value(vh or a valid height on parent to calculate percentage), your code works as expected   https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vJvYKG

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you use `flex: 0 0 70px;` combined with either `min-height: 0;` or `overflow: hidden`, it should make sure the `A` always stays 70px high.

The first `0` is *flex-grow* which prevent it from grow, the second `0` is *flex-shrink* which prevent it from shrink, and the `min-height`/`overflow` will allow it to also be smaller than its content, which by default it is not (`min-height` defaults to `auto`, which prevent a flex item be smaller than its content).

The last `70px` is *flex-basis* which is the Flexbox version for `height`, and I recommend you use that instead.

*Note, you are missing an `n` in `colum` for the `flex-direction` value.*

```css
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 90vh;
    background: lightgray;
}

.A {
    flex: 0 0 70px;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 0;
    background: lightblue;
}

.B {
    margin: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
    flex-grow: 1;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="A">A</div>
    <div class="B">B</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect solution! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the contents of B is "taller" than the height of B, B grows in height to somehow accommodate the contents. This causes the height of A to decrease to adjust. In order to disallow A from shrinking, add `flex-shrink: 0` to its styles.